# Accessing main activity in Broadcast Reciever without using intent

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, main-activity

I am stuck in a problem. I have a broadcast receiver that calls the method of class takes in context and main activity reference in constructor. I dont know how to access main activity in broadcast receiver.Here is my code:

```
public void onReceive(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
        if (context == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (info != null) {
            if (info.isConnected()) { 
                if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                     Class myclass = new Class(context,mainactivity reference); //dont know how to get main activity here
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Is there is any way that I can get it without Intent or there is some other method. I am in learning phase any help will be appreciated.

In manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="myreceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this hope it works:
in Main Activity:
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static MainActivity getInstance() {
    return new MainActivity();
}
}
And in your receiver:
MainActivity reference=MainActivity.getInstance();
```

Comment: The method you proposed will not in my case because in my case I am updating a textview in main activity from "Class" class and it will throw null pointer in that case

Comment: then you have to give reference to  main activity in on create method after inistialize ui..and use this reference in getInstance().

Comment: hope it work:  static MainActivity ref=null ;                                                             
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //// Initialize ui 
        ref=this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   }                                    
  public static MainActivity getInstance() {
    return ref;
}

Comment: Thank you very much. you solved my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I dont know how to access main activity in broadcast receiver

You don't. If this is a manifest-registered receiver, you may not have an instance of this activity, anyway.

Either:

- Register the receiver from inside the `Activity`, via `registerReceiver()`, in which case your nested `BroadcastReceiver` class can reference the outer `Activity` instance, or
- Use an event bus (greenrobot's EventBus, `LocalBroadcastManager`, etc.) to publish your event, and have your activity subscribe on that bus (if the activity happens to be around)

Comment: I could not understand your first line about registration. I have registered it in manifest see my edited code in the post

Comment: @exceptionnotgood: Your process does not live forever. So, the user starts your app from the home screen launcher. The user then leaves your app. Your process is terminated. Then a connectivity change occurs. At this point, you receive the broadcast (at least on older Android devices), but you have no activity. A `BroadcastReceiver` registered in the manifest, as yours is, cannot make *any* assumptions about what activities may or may not exist in the process.

Comment: thank you for you detailed explanation. So what should I do now?